# How to change timezone in read-only rootfs in Yocto poky warrior

Tags: yocto, systemd, readonly

I am trying to change the timezone on an embedded Linux (Yocto poky warrior) for Raspberry-pi Cm3.
But I am unable to do so. I get an error message stating

```
root@raspberrypi-cm3:~# timedatectl set-timezone "America/New_York"
Failed to set time zone: Failed to set time zone: Read-only file system
```

This worked before changing the rootfs to read-only.

How can I change timezone on read-only rootfs?

Comment: If your whole rootfs is read-only, you cannot configure anything at runtime. If you want partial configurability, you need parts of the filesystem to be writable (options include a separate mount point for /etc or creating symlinks for specific files in /etc at build time that point to another, writable, filesystem location)

Comment: @JussiKukkonen I actually did that. I moved `/etc/localtime` and `/etc/timzone` to a writable portion of the filesystem. But I think the problem is that `timedated.c` file looks for `/etc/localtime` Which I think I have to change. But I am not an embedded developer. And I am having some issues understanding the code. Can I add those questions to this page?

Comment: See: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/8277. TL;DR: not really possible out of the box, you'll need to either pick (and maintain) the suggested patch there or use overlayfs or other kinds of work arounds. Basically, /etc/localtime is recreated (by an equivalent of `ln -fs`) by timedated when needed... which obviously can't be done because it's on an RO FS.

Comment: @qschulz you are a god sent. I love you. Can you please make this comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/etc/localtime is recreated (by an equivalent of `ln -fs`) by timedated when needed... which obviously can't be done because it's on an RO FS.

It's not really possible out of the box, you'll need to either pick (and maintain) the following patch or use overlayfs or other kinds of work-arounds.

See [this](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/8277) for full explanation.

Comment: How are you using the `TIMEDATEDIR` ?

Comment: Once I do that. I do see a mismatch between `date` and `timedatectl`.

Comment: I'm not working for the company which uses this trick anymore, so can't answer (it's been 2 years and a half since ;) ). IIUC my own post, you need to create the symlink between `/etc/localtime` and `/path/rw/localtime` so that non-timedated tools can still access it. If symlinks aren't followed, you'll probably need to patch whatever tool is reading `/etc/localtime` directly instead of following the symlinks.